# Use remote git repository for Dokku

Tags: git, continuous-deployment, dokku

I have deployed my app by Dokku. It is easy to use and helpful. But in Dokku you need to add new remote in git. For example,

```
git remote add dokku dokku@dokku.me:app
```

However, I want to use my github.com repository. I should push my project to master branch and my hosted app should update.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dokku` remote is for deployment to your server. You can use your github.com repository as your `origin` remote for working on your code.

Create the `origin` github.com remote, if it has not been created already, and push your code to it. Check your code in here as you make changes.

When you are ready to deploy your latest changes to your hosted application, you will push to `dokku` with `git push dokku master`.

Answer (score 0):

[Continuous Deployment with Codeship and Dokku](https://blog.sethbergman.com/continuous-deployment-with-codeship-and-dokku/)

The following steps will help you successfully deploy from Codeship to Dokku. This will not take long to implement. You only need the public ssh key from your Codeship project and the bash scripts below.

Save the public key of the Codeship project. It is found in Project Settings > General Settings.

In project repo create a folder labeled tmp, then save the ssh key as codeship_projectname.pub.

Make sure when pasting, all the contents are in a single line and not multiple lines.

Add the public key to your dokku server using the following command in console.
​

```sh
cat tmp/codeship_projectname.pub | ssh root@dokkuinstance.com "sudo sshcommand acl-add dokku codeship_projectname"
```

In Codeship, go to Project Settings > Deployment. Configure your deployment pipeline.

Add a new custom script.

Add the following lines to the custom script.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
git fetch --unshallow || true
git fetch origin "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
# checkout a remote branch with
# git checkout -b test origin/test
git remote add dokku dokku@dokkuinstance.com:projectname
git push dokku master
```

Now every time you build on Codeship, it should deploy to your Dokku server.

[Here's a tutorial on my blog. Hope this helps!](https://blog.sethbergman.com/continuous-deployment-with-codeship-and-dokku/)